# How can I send different "New User" email depending on user class in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

We would like to be able to modify to outgoing New User notification so that it first checks the user class, then sends out a different pre made NUn based on its findings.

**For example:**

*An employee/internal user gets an email that says:*

Hello (Insert Employee name)!

Your password must be updated. Please login at https://ouracumatica.hostedsomewhere.com using the following credentials where you will be prompted to change your password:

Username: your Email address
Password: users password

Please visit https://ouracumatica.hostedsomewhere.com

Blah, blah blah.

*But an unlimited external user would get:*

Hello (Insert contact name)!

Your password must be updated https://portal.ouracumatica.hostedsomewhere.com using the following credentials where you will be prompted to change your password:

Username: Your Email address
Password: users password

For Help visit: https://portal.ouracumatica.hostedsomewhere.com/WTHAmIDoing/

(Different Blah, blah blah.)

Attachment 1
Attachment 2

It seems to be hardcoded to only sent one no matter the class in "Email Preferences" Screen (SM204001)